# Document Processing Library

Tags: nlp

I am doing a project which includes document classification component. I need a library which can be used to pre-process the documents and transform it to a feature matrix. Are there any library available for that?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two famous Java libraries

Java based

Stanford core NLP - http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/classifier.shtml

GATE - http://osdir.com/ml/ai.gate.general/2007-05/msg00003.html, https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch19.html#chap:ml

Python based

NLTK - http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used weka for document processing. It is sufficient for most of the document processing operations. It contains filter that can be used to transfer documents to feature vectors. It can be used as follows,

```
        StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector(); //create new filter for vector transformation

        NGramTokenizer tokenizer = new NGramTokenizer(); //tokenizer for filter
        tokenizer.setNGramMinSize(1); 
        tokenizer.setNGramMaxSize(1);
        tokenizer.setDelimiters("\\W");


        SnowballStemmer stemmer = new SnowballStemmer();  //Initializes stemmer 
        stemmer.setStemmer("english"); //set english stemmer


        filter.setLowerCaseTokens(true); 
        filter.setOutputWordCounts(true); 

        filter.setTFTransform(true); //   //Tf–idf can be successfully used for stop-words filtering in various subject fields including text summarization and classification.
        filter.setIDFTransform(true);      
        filter.setStopwords(new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\SVM implementation\\StopWordsR4.txt")); // stop word removal 
        filter.setTokenizer(tokenizer); 
        filter.setStemmer(stemmer);
```

For more details use [this](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html)